# Opscenter 3.2.x not working on Debian 7

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

After upgrading to Debian7, opscenter refuses to start with the following error:

```
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: Log opened.
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: twistd 10.2.0 (/usr/bin/python2.7 2.7.3) starting up.
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: set uid/gid 0/0
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: Logging level set to 'info'
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: OpsCenter version: 3.2.1
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: Compatible agent version: 3.2.1
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: Loading per-cluster config file /etc/opscenter/clusters/MLX_TEST.conf
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: HTTP BASIC authentication enabled
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: Starting webserver with ssl disabled.
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 []  INFO: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-08-12 10:09:05+0200 [] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 317, in startApplication
            app.startApplication(application, not self.config['no_save'])
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/application/app.py", line 653, in startApplication
            service.IService(application).startService()
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/application/service.py", line 277, in startService
            service.startService()
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1141, in unwindGenerator
            return _inlineCallbacks(None, f(*args, **kwargs), Deferred())
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/OpsCenterdService.py", line 51, in startService

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/OpsCenterdService.py", line 136, in setupClusterManager

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/ClusterServices.py", line 66, in __init__

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/ClusterServices.py", line 264, in makeStatsReporter

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/StatsReporter.py", line 60, in makeReporter

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/StatsReporter.py", line 42, in __init__

          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/SslUtils.py", line 3, in <module>

          File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
            import rand, crypto, SSL, tsafe
        exceptions.ImportError: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

there seems to be no candidate for libssl0.9.8; which has been suggested in other questions:

```
esb-a-test:~# apt-get install libssl0.9.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl0.9.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8' has no installation candidate
```

I do see the lib in /usr/lib32 ; but not in /usr/lib

Comment: I would say it is better to ask this on DataStax forums.

Comment: Thats how I got here: 
http://planetcassandra.org/Learn/QA?id=datastax-community

Comment: Oh, ok I see. Sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, but the workaround is documented here:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/3.2/webhelp/#opsc/troubleshooting/opscTroubleshooting_g.html#topic_opsc_troubleshooting

See the section relating to that import error.